# running simple TRNG code on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

I have run the following codes to install TRNG:

```
mkdir build 
cd build 
cmake ..
make 
make install
```

and I think the installation has been successful. when I run my program with this `g++ -o 1.cpp -ltrng4` it says :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltrng4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libtrng4 is not a Ubuntu ubuntu package and your error indicates that its not installed..

Suggest you have a go at installing it from scratch:-

```
https://github.com/rabauke/trng4
```

Installation instructions are here:-
https://github.com/rabauke/trng4/raw/master/doc/trng.pdf

```
git clone https://github.com/rabauke/trng4 
cd trng4
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
make install
```

If all of that worked then your compile line should be:-

g++ -o 1.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -ltrng4

Comment: I did several time with scratch following the commands found on this pdf

Comment: Compilation of the TRNG library generates a static as well as a shared library unless TRNG is compiled in Visual Studio where only static libraries are supported by CMake. Depending on your system further steps might be necessary to make the TRNG shared library known to the dynamic linker. On a Linux system the system administrator has to call ldconfig or you might set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. See also the ld.so man page for further information.

Comment: What did you set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to and does it match where your libtrng4.so or libtrng4.a file is installed?

Comment: after `make install`, I ran ` sudo ldconfig` only. Would not be enough? because it has mentioned run l`dconfig` or set variable.

Comment: I think I should run ldconfig with a path. But, I am not sure which path should I address to

Comment: The default install directory for cmake in this instance is /usr/local/ so your includes are in /usr/local/include and libs are in /usr/local/lib.

So unless you setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH or use -L/usr/local/lib on your g++ line its not going to pick it up.

Comment: I've updated the answer above.. to include you updated compile line..

g++ -o 1.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -ltrng4

Comment: Again the same error :((( `g++ -o 1.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -ltrng4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltrng4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Do ls -l /usr/local/lib/

Comment: And make sure you did make install ;-)

Comment: I checked now and It is not installed and I do not know why:( I followed the instruction on the pdf and the only error I got was that `could not find TBB` and I think that is no harm

Comment: Should I take this message seriously ?

Comment: Running from scratch again: `CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:117 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "boost_unit_test_framework" (requested version 1.71.0) with any of the
  following names:

    boost_unit_test_frameworkConfig.cmake
    boost_unit_test_framework-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_unit_test_framework" to
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "boost_unit_test_framework_DIR" to a directory
  containing one of the above files.`

Comment: Looks like you have some missing dependancies...
I did a complete install as per my instructions on a Raspberry pi running ubuntu 20.10 with zero issues..

Comment: apt update

then 


apt install build-essential

Comment: I downloaded dependencies regarding boost and now I have moved from the step of `make`. the final message after `make` is :`Built target test_all`
 but running `make install` says that CMake Error at trng/cmake_install.cmake:46 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file "/home/username/trng4/build/trng/libtrng4.a"
  to "/usr/local/lib/libtrng4.a": Permission denied.
Call Stack (most recent call first):` Did you also try to install in default location?

Comment: That's user your user doesn't have permission to install..

sudo make install

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! it is now installed , I checked the directory it was there . However, still cannot compile. running the command you mentioned returns this: `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Please edit the running command : `g++ -o 1 1.cpp -ltrng4` now this worked!